# Import Picasso library issues

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I'm trying to show images using `Picasso` library but I'm encountering some problems.
I added this

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1'
}
```

in the `build.gradle` but I have a problem and I'm stuck. Could you help me please?
[image]

Sorry for the dummy question but there's always the first time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button at the top.

[image: button]

Comment: No problem, I have this issue constantly and have to remember to do this. :)